# Locating nearby Shopping Malls and their Stores using GPS/Wifi in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-maps

I want to develop an android application, that gets my current location thru GPS and displays me the nearby Shopping Malls and their Shops.

So for i  have learned about [Location API](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html) from vogella.de ..

Again i saw discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-an) about getting current location.

I got success in getting current location so far.

When i searched for such applications in itunes, i got two apps..

1st [ClipMobile](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/clip-mobile/id350896181?mt=8).

2nd  [Armadealo Shopping](http://itunes.apple.com/app/armadealo-shopping/id335045255?mt=8)

I want to display this things in android. How can i start ? See the screenshots :

[image] [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pieces you need are:
(A) determine user's position
(B) search a point of interest (POI) database for nearby shopping malls
(C) plot results on a map display

Sounds like you're set on (A). For (B), I recommend looking at the POI offerings from [SimpleGeo](https://simplegeo.com/products/places/) or [CloudMade](http://datamarket.cloudmade.com/). (Note that if you're going for non-U.S. coverage, you may need to find different POI providers.) And for (C) you can use [Google Maps for Android](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html) or [CloudMade's SDK](http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/show/mobile-sdks).

Comment: Yaa i am going for non-U.S. coverage...What is POI Offerings ?

Comment: CloudMade does offer data for other countries too: http://datamarket.cloudmade.com/

Comment: Thanks alot for immediate response. great one..Yaa but i didn find India in CloudMade too..They are not offering data for India.

Comment: Sure, you're welcome. If Google has POI coverage for India, you may be able to use that through their new Places API: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/

Answer (score 1):

Google offers this through their Google Places API. For some basic info on how to get started with the Google Places API see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549608/want-near-by-location-information-within-1km-range).

Information on the Google Places REST API can be found at the [The Google Places API (Developer Preview)](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#ApplicationForm)

AFAIK, there is no clean-cut client library available, but here's [a blog post](http://blog.brianbuikema.com/2010/08/android-development-part-1-using-googles-places-api-to-develop-compelling-location-based-mobile-applications/) on how to properly sign the requests to the Google Places API. The request themselves are covered in the Google docs.

Comment: Yaa i saw your answer in that question before you posted here. But is there any implementation of Google Places Of Interest API ?. I want to learn it. Because if i will start randomly, i am sure i wont b able to get anything later.

Comment: Google offers an implementation. The Place Search and Place Details Requests requests should cover what you need here.

Comment: where can i find example related to Google Places API ?. I already have googled out, but it didnt gave returned with anything yet.