# Want near by location information within 1KM range

Tags: android

I am working on a application which gives me all near by places within 1km range from my current location. I am able to get longitude and latitute of the current location using LocationManager class in android. Using this information i want to get information (i.e. long/lati) of the nearby places. I have seen some of the webservices alos but couldn't get the answer. Please help me.

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291573/how-to-find-hospital-location-near-by-my-location/10479656#10479656) that cantain how to do with near by location

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [Places API Application Form](http://gmaps-ws-console.appspot.com/) that you'll need to fill in in order to get access to the Google Places API. This application will be verified by Google and they'll provide you with the necessary access.

You'll also need a [Google Adsense](https://www.google.com/adsense) Publisher ID (

More info on the Places API can be found here :

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/

Comment: [plaece api example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291573/how-to-find-hospital-location-near-by-my-location/10479656#10479656)